# undefined output with Array.prototype.reduce

Tags: javascript

Why the following code produce undefined as output?

```
function sumAll(arr) {  
  arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b );
}
sumAll([1,2,3,4]);
```

While if i run this code without the function like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]; 
arr.reduce( (prev, curr) => prev + curr );
```

it works properly and produce 10 as sum of all elements.

What's wrong with the first one? I'm pretty new to JS that's why i can't figure it out what's wrong with the first one.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You left out your `return` keyword.

Comment: @Tushar no, in a case like this there's no need for the last parameter

Comment: my bad for asking such a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sumAll` function doesn't have any return value, and you're not using the return value it doesn't have. Add `return` before the `reduce` call, and use it:

```js
function sumAll(arr) {  
    return arr.reduce( (a, b) => a + b );
//  ^^^^^^---- Return the result
}
console.log(sumAll([1,2,3,4])); // Use the result
```

The reason you saw a result with your second code block is that you were running it in a JavaScript console, which always automatically shows you the result of the last thing you did.